# Did Gohan evolve in the tournament of power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the last episode of Dragon Ball Super, Vegeta tells Vermouth that he can't be sure Goku won't master Ultra Instinct as he has seen how the Saiyans have evolved in the tournament of power. In that moment, they show scenes of Vegeta's new transformation, Cabba turning into Super Saiyan 2, Kefla performing her final attack, and Gohan fighting Koicherator. Did Gohan's power evolve during the tournament of power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gohan did get a lot stronger during the short period before the tournament. He could barely turn SSJ during the exhibition matches, however, we see him turn Ultimate Gohan and get even more stronger compared to the Buu Saga and his current power level is very likely superior to even SSJG Goku.

During the course of the tournament, Gohan didn't really have as much of a chance in getting a Zenkai boost unlike the other situations because he's never been in a life or death situation like the others. However, him managing to overpower *Koicherator* by himself, holding his own against Saonel and Pirina, also taking out *Dyspo who was indeed a threat*, indicates that he did have an evolution in power. Considering what he was from the Start of Super, in the Exhibition Matches and now in the Tournament of power.